# Aggregate in pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, aggregate

I try this

```
declare @t as table (yea int, rating varchar(100))

insert into @t 
values (2012, 'US'), (2013, 'S'), (2014, 'G'),
       (2015, 'E'), (2016, 'E')     

--select * from @T

select 
    [2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2016]
from 
    (select rating
     from @T) p 
pivot
    (max (rating) 
     for rating in ([2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2016])) as pb
```

and I got this result:

```
2012    2013    2014    2015    2016
--------------------------------------
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

but I would really like this result instead:

```
2012    2013    2014    2015    2016
-------------------------------------
US      S       G       E       E
```

Is this null data because of `max(rating)`? If so - how do I get the desired data?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing **yea**  (not sure if yea was a typo so I left it as is)

```
declare @t as table (yea int, rating varchar(100))
        insert into @t values (2012,'US')       
        insert into @t values (2013,'S')                
        insert into @t values (2014,'G')
        insert into @t values (2015,'E')        
        insert into @t values (2016,'E')        
        --select * from @T
        select [2012],[2013],[2014],[2015],[2016]
            from 
            (select yea,rating
            from @T 
            ) p 
            pivot
            (max (rating) for yea in ([2012],[2013],[2014],[2015],[2016])) as pb
```

Returns

```
2012    2013    2014    2015    2016
US      S       G       E       E
```